# How to disable quickfix validation

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I need to disable quickfix validation.

Setting UseDataDictionary=N does not work.
Removing paths to dictionary files in the config file does not work.
Renaming xml files in the directory to some other extension does not work.

Still rejecting messages based on failed validation.

The directory is correct.  Please help!  I'm sure I am missing something trivial.

Thank you!

PS - in reply to some questions:
The error I am getting is: 58=Tag specified out of required order 371=143 372=8

Indeed, the client is sending tag 143 in the message body, not the header.  The client will not change the code.  I tried adding tag 143 to the ExecutionReport body, but that did not help.  I am weary of taking tag 143 out of the header just for these guys.

PS - config file:

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=log
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=N
DataDictionary=/xxxxxx
TransportDataDictionary=/xxxxx
ResetOnLogon=N
DefaultApplVerID=9

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=xxxxxx
TargetCompID=xxxxxx
SocketConnectHost=xxxxxxxxx
SocketConnectPort=52400
HeartBtInt=30
```

Comment: can you show and error please

Comment: `Several standard files are in included in the spec directory.` Did you check this location ? Did you try debugging to see which all path it is trying to read from ?

Comment: please share example config parameters and rejection FIX message, i can help.

Comment: does the message contain any repeating groups?

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I added the error and the config file to post.

Comment: @MD-Tech, yes, the message contains repeating groups (The PartyID group)

Comment: @DumbCoder are you referring to the dictionary directory?  If so, I specify it, and yes, it's reading from there ( I broke, then fixed the xml files to be sure)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable this specific check by setting the `ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder` parameter to `N` in your configuration file.  See [Configuring QuickFIX](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have to have UseDataDictionary=Y if you have repeating groups, it tells QuickFIX how to handle items in repeated groups. "Tag specified out of required order 371=143 372=8" *usually*  means that a header tag is in the message body, a body tag is in the header, a repeating group tag is in the body, a body tag is in a repeated group etc.. Since the client is sending tag 143 in the message body rather than the header you will need to edit the DataDictionary so that that tag appears in the message body instead of the header. Since you can set the DataDictionary on a per connection basis I would *strongly* recommend that you create a copy of the original dictionary, give it a client specific name and edit that file and then connect it to that connection keeping the original clean.

Comment: MD-Tech, Thank you. Adding 143 to the body wasn't enough, I had to take it out of the header first. Now there are no more rejects. HOWEVER, now the fix engine is not printing nor propagating the message to the application level... I wonder if there's something else wrong but there is no output. When the FIX engine was rejecting it, it was printing the reject it was sending to the client, NOT the actual message itself. Now, with 143 moved from header to body, there is no ExecutionReport message AND no Reject in the logs. First line of code in the application isn't triggered either...

Comment: Sorry I had meant you to take it out of the header when I said "instead of". What is the "First line of code in the application" you expect to be triggered? Is it an OnMessage call? If so which one?